# NSParagraphStyle is changed when resigning UITextField's first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextField` in a custom `UITableViewCell` whose text I would like to truncate from the head, not the tail.

I am setting the line break mode in `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  [super awakeFromNib];

  NSMutableDictionary* textAttributes = [self.textField.defaultTextAttributes mutableCopy];
  NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [self.textField.defaultTextAttributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] mutableCopy];
  paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead;
  [textAttributes setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
  [textAttributes setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
  self.textField.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes;
}
```

While it gets set, leaving the text field (resigning the first responder) seems to cause the `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTrail` to be used instead.

The change happens somewhere between `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:`: When I set breakpoints in both methods, the line break mode in the first is `NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead` but `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` by the second.

Is there a way that I can set the line break mode and have it stick?

Answer (score 1):

I know, this question is not new, but I'm struggling with that problem since hours and the only way I found it working at the end was the following (hope it helps other people struggling with that problem).

Override the `drawTextInRect` method of `UITextField` and set the `defaultTextAttributes` elsewhere in code (I did it in `init` method in my custom `UITextField` subclass):

```
- (void) drawTextInRect : (CGRect) rect {
    [[self text] drawInRect: rect withAttributes: self.defaultTextAttributes];
}
```

... and elsewhere in code:

```
// get defaultTextAttributes of the TextField
NSMutableDictionary* textAttributes = [self.defaultTextAttributes mutableCopy];
// get default paragraph style from the defaultTextAttributes    
NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [textAttributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] mutableCopy];
// change the lineBreakMode as desired
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead;
// put changed paragraphStyle into textAttributes    
[textAttributes setObject: paragraphStyle forKey: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
// set the defaultTextAttributes of the textField    
self.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes;
```